# SOLVED: How to reroute Arduino/ESP Serial output at run time?

Tags: logging, arduino-c++

I am using a logging library in Arduino environment that is mostly depending on preprocessor magic - for the benefit of not compiling any code into the binary that does not fit the set logging level and having file name, function name and line numbers available without much ado.

Output is done with `Serial.printf` normally. So a statement like

```
LOG_N("%02X/%02X @%d/%d? (heap=%d)\n", sv, fc, ad, ln, ESP.getFreeHeap() - lastHeap);
```

is expanded to

```
if (MBUlogLvl >= level) Serial.printf("[N] %lu| %-20s [%4d] %s: %02X/%02X @%d/%d? (heap=%d)\n", millis(), file_name(__FILE__), __LINE__, __func__, sv, fc, ad, ln, ESP.getFreeHeap() - lastHeap);
```

(with a couple of intermediate preprocessor macro expansions involved)

The `Serial.printf` is `LOGDEVICE->printf` internally, with `Print *LOGDEVICE = &Serial;` somewhere else.

While this is working fine as long as I am able to use `Serial`, it is inappropriate for situations where the MCU is sitting somewhere in the field with no access to the `Serial` output. I do have another helper class setting up a Telnet server, where log output is distributed to all clients connected.

I am failing miserably, though, to connect both. I seem not be able to switch the `Serial.printf` to the required `TelnetLog.printf` successfully at compile or run time.

I tried so far:

- `#define LOGSTMT TelnetLog.printf` and use `LOGSTMT` instead of `LOGDEVICE->printf`. The issue here is that the modification needs to be done in the logging library header to affect all parts of the code (the library is used in other libraries as well that are provided externally). I can modify the logging library, but only once to not repeatedly break the other libraries' codes.
- using `LOGDEVICE = &tlog;` - `tlog` is an instance of class `TelnetLog`, that is derived from `Print`. While this is working in principle, due to `LOGDEVICE` being a pointer to `Print`, the `TelnetLog.printf` is not used, but the `Print.write` - and in turn `TelnetLog.write` function is used for output, since `Print.write` is virtual. This is highly inefficient for multiple TCP clients to be provided, as every single character would be sent separately.
- using function pointers to the respective `printf` of `Serial` or `TelnetLog`. I did not manage to get something compiled at all.

Here is my example code. For the sake of readability I am using the `AltLog` class instead of `TelnetLog` here. `AltLog` just doubles the output to Serial:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <typeinfo>

class AltLog : public Print {
public:
  size_t write(uint8_t c) {
    Serial.printf("/1: %c", c);
    Serial.printf("/2: %c", c);
    return 5;
  }

  template <typename... Args>
  size_t printf(const char *format, Args&&... args) {
    size_t len = 0;
    char fmt[strlen(format) + 4];
    strcpy(fmt, "/1: ");
    strcat(fmt, format);
    len = Serial.printf(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    strcpy(fmt, "/2: ");
    strcat(fmt, format);
    len = Serial.printf(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    return len;
  }
};

AltLog a;

Print *device = &Serial;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("_OK_");
  delay(5000);

  Serial.printf("%s\n", typeid(*device).name());
  device->printf("Serial.%c\n", 'S');

  device = &a;

  Serial.printf("%s\n", typeid(*device).name());
  dynamic_cast<AltLog *>(device)->printf("Alternate.%c\n", 'A');
  device->printf("Alternate.%c\n", 'A');

}

void loop() {
}
```

This *does* work, but it is no solution, as it requires the `dynamic_cast` I cannot have in the logging lib. The output is like:

```
_OK_
14HardwareSerial
Serial.S
6AltLog
/1: Alternate.A
/2: Alternate.A
/1: A/2: A/1: l/2: l/1: t/2: t/1: e/2: e/1: r/2: r/1: n/2: n/1: a/2: a/1: t/2: t/1: e/2: e/1: ./2: ./1: A/2: A/1:
/2:
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my special case I found a solution (the general question remains open, though).

The `Print` class of the Arduino/ESP32 core has another virtual function `size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)`. As this is not pure virtual, I did not notice it.

`Print::printf()` is using this `write` variety to put out data. The default implementation of the `write` is using the single-char variant of `write` (the pure virtual function that needs to be implemented in derived classes). Thus a call of `device->printf()` will use `Print::printf()` and in turn `Print::write()` and finally `AltLog::write()`. The `AltLog::printf()` never comes into play at all.

Implementing the `AltLog::write(buffer, size)` function solves the dilemma for me, the complete buffer can be sent as one now.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

class AltLog : public Print {
public:
  size_t write(uint8_t c) {
    Serial.printf("/1: %c", c);
    Serial.printf("/2: %c", c);
    return 5;
  }

  size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {
    Serial.print("/1: ");
    Serial.write(buffer, size);
    Serial.print("/2: ");
    Serial.write(buffer, size);
    return 4 + size;
  }
};

AltLog a;

Print *device = &Serial;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("_OK_");
  delay(5000);

  device->printf("Serial.%c\n", 'S');

  device = &a;
  device->printf("Alternate.%c\n", 'A');

}

void loop() {
}
```